# str_replace, strstr and substr in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a Wordpress project and I need to strip down an image link that's generated from [placehold.it](http://placehold.it) and extract the text from the query string. However, I need to implement a `str_replace` and a `substr` and a `strstr` function - but it all needs to be done within javascript (ideally jQuery if there's a way).

So here is the img src:

```
http://via.placeholder.com/387x232/E9967A/f0b9a6?text=30ft+x+50ft
```

I need to strip this down to generate the following string:

> 30-50

which I do like this, in PHP:

```
str_replace(array("=","ft","+","x"),array("","","","-"),substr(strstr($text,"="),0));
```

But how would I do the above in javascript? And is there potentially an easier and more compact way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried `.replace("old", "new");` in JavaScript?

Comment: And .substr(startindex,endindexexclusive)

Comment: But what about the other functions? Specifically the substr to cut out everything before the '=' sign?

Comment: Sorry - I saw Jonas w answer after I posted the above!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use any of those. I'd use a regular expression. *What* regular expression would depend on what parts of that string are unchanging. For instance:

```
var result = str.match(/\d+(?=ft)/g).join("-");
```

That searches for a series of digits followed by `ft` (without consuming the `ft`, via a *positive lookahead assertion*) and joins the resulting array of matches into a string delimited with `-`.

Live example:

```js
var str = "http://via.placeholder.com/387x232/E9967A/f0b9a6?text=30ft+x+50ft";
var result = str.match(/\d+(?=ft)/g).join("-");
console.log(result);
```

---

In terms of what JavaScript functions you'd use for situations where you *would* want `str_replace`, etc., in PHP, here's a list:

- [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) - Replace characters defined by a literal string or a regular expression with literal replacements, tokenized replacements, or a replacement function.
- [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) - Get a substring using an index and length, where the index can be negative to indicate starting from the end.
- [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) - Get a substring using start and end indexes.

More: [`String` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [`String.prototype` functions in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-string-prototype-object)

Comment: I think using a regular expression is the best way to go. Much tidier and concise. Thank you.

Comment: i think a combination of both is a nice way
`str.split('=').pop().match(/\d+/g).join('-')`

Answer (score 1):

```
var size=string.split("=")[1].split("ft").join("").split("+x+").join("-");
```

Simply take everything behind the =

```
.split("=")[1]
```

remove all *ft* :

```
.split("ft").join("")
```

And replace the *+x+* with *-* :

```
.split("+x+").join("-");
//or
.replace("+x+","-");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with php you can try to use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.parse-url.php) and then [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get exact values from the part of parsed url.

Example:

```
<?php

$parsedUrl = parse_url('http://via.placeholder.com/387x232/E9967A/f0b9a6?text=30ft+x+50ft', PHP_URL_QUERY);

var_dump($parsedUrl);
// Output: string(16) "text=30ft+x+50ft"

$expression = preg_match('/.*?(\d+).*?(\d+)/is', $parsedUrl, $matches);

if ($expression) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Final output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "text=30ft+x+50"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "30"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "50"
}
```